# Best way to remove selected elements from slice

Tags: go

I have a slice A and another slice B. Slice A contains n elements and slice B is a subset of slice A where each element is a pointer to Slice A.

What would be the cheapest method to remove all elements from A which is referred in B.

After bit of googling only method I can think of is to reslice slice A for each element in B. Is that is only method or is there a simpler one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have a slice A and another slice B. Slice A contains n elements and
>   slice B is a subset of slice A where each element is a pointer to
>   Slice A.
>
> What would be the cheapest method to remove all elements from A which
>   is referred in B.

A and B may have duplicates and may not be sorted.

---

For example, growth rate O(n),

```
package main

import "fmt"

func remove(a []int, b []*int) []int {
    d := make(map[*int]bool, len(b))
    for _, e := range b {
        d[e] = true
    }
    var c []int
    if len(a) >= len(d) {
        c = make([]int, 0, len(a)-len(d))
    }
    for i := range a {
        if !d[&a[i]] {
            c = append(c, a[i])
        }
    }
    return c
}

func main() {
    a := []int{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7}
    fmt.Println(a)
    b := []*int{&a[1], &a[3], &a[3], &a[7], &a[4]}
    a = remove(a, b)
    fmt.Println(a)
}
```

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/-RpkH51FSt2

Output:

```
[0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7]
[0 2 5 6]
```